# How to make complicated polymorphic relationships in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

We are just switching to laravel in my workplace and I still have problems with using more complicated relationships.

I have the following models:

**Company**

- id
- name
- ...

**Domain**

- id
- url
- company_id -> belongs to Company
- ...

**CommunicationEvent**

- id
- name (like: OrderPlaced)
- ...

**Email**

- id
- name
- subject
- body
- company_id -> belongs to Company
- ...

**SMS**
similary to Email

Every Company should be able to set the communication to be used in an Event and in an event multiple type of communications can be used. For example, if an OrderPlaced event fires they can choose to have both an email and an SMS to be sent. Moreover they can set a default email/sms for all of their domains in an event and just overwrite it for one of their domains to use a different one there.

My first shot was to make a pivot table with event_id, company_id, domain_id(nullable for default) and communicable_id/type. I made a test relationship like this into CommunicationEvent:

```
public function mails(){
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Mail', 'communicable', 'comm_event_comms', 'event_id', 'communicable_id')->where('comm_event_comms.company_id', 1);
}
```

And I put dummy data into the table, but `$event->mails` returns empty. Reading the documentation made me think I'm not on the right track.

Honestly, I don't really know how to properly connect these models so I can use them easyly. The only way I could make it work was to use DB::where... queries, but nothing with relationships. :(

Can you please help to build a relationship between these models?

Comment: The idea of a polymorphic relationship is that it is stored in one database table, but can "morph" from one model to another based on the data received. So step 1 would be to have a single table for email and SMS, and then you set up a pivot table between that table and your events table. Sharing your (minimal) model code and your working SQL query might help people understand what you're attempting.

Comment: And do look at the documentation examples. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships In your case, `posts`=`emails`, `videos`=`sms`, `tags`=`events`, and `taggables`=your new polymorphic table

Comment: And one last suggestion is to keep in mind Laravel naming conventions when you create models. `Sms` is not great since you'll end up doing things like `$event->smss` which can lead to typos. Best to stick with single-word class names that are unambiguously singular.

Comment: @miken32 Thanks! I reread documentation and realized where I went wrong. Also I will most certainly use the name TextMessage for SMS, after I get the whole functional specification for it and can start on that part. :)

Answer (score 1):

I realized what was the problem with the relationship. I should have used `morphedByMany` instead of `morphToMany`. Thanks to miken32 I reread documentation and realized this on 3rd read.

The right relationship in communicationEvent:

```
public function mails(){
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Communication\Mail', 'communicable', 'communicables', 'event_id')->where('communicables.company_id', DData::getCompanyId());
    }
```

I also changed the name of the pivot table to communicables for convention.

Like that `$event->mails()->attach($mail_id, ['company_id' => DData::getCompanyId()]);` works perfectly to set default email communication for event. And setting domain specific communication works as well with additional `domain_id` data in attach.

I can use `$event->mails` as well for select.

The only problem that remained is detaching. As I read [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/detach-on-many-to-many-relationship):

> ...if you're storing other data on a "pivot" it's not really a pivot
> anymore...

I don't think I will be able to solve that with a simple `detach()` method so I used db queries like this:

```
DB::table('communicables')->where([
                            ['event_id', $event->id],
                            ['domain_id', NULL],
                            ['company_id', DData::getCompanyId()]
                        ])->delete();
```

I will have to search for communicable type as well when I connect the SMS model, but I decided it is a good enough solution. Other solution would have been to make a separate model for comminicables table, but I didn't wanted that.